# racket pattern matching set

Tags: pattern-matching, racket

I wonder pattern matching a set in Racket is possible? My certain case is algebraic identities, for example, `2*a` can be `a+a`. However, currently, I match on `list` then I have to write `(or (list '* 2 a) (list '* a 2))`. If matching on `set` is possible, then I can have `(set '* 2 a)`, which is easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `list-no-order`. Use it only for small sets though.

In programs that needs to work on mathematical expressions, a standard technique is to "normalize" expressions before using any matching.
Her "normalize" means to "sort" the arguments according to some order.

In `racket-cas` normalization will put numbers before symbols. And sort the symbols in alphabetical order.

```
#lang racket
(require racket-cas)
(normalize '(+ b 3 a))
```

The result will be:

```
(+ 3 a b)
```

If you are interested in writing a CAS on you own, I recommend
buying or borrowing the two books by Cohen.

https://www.amazon.com/Joel-S-Cohen/e/B001K8MI06/ref=dp_byline_cont_pop_ebooks_1

Comment: I assume CAS means "computer algebra system"...?